# Call a MySQL stored procedure with Flask-MySQLdb

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python

I've created a stored procedure `spCreateUser` in MySQL and I need to pass two arguments to it using Flask-MySQLdb. What is the correct way to pass multiple arguments to a stored procedure?

I tried using `execute` but I got the error `not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

```
cur.execute('spCreateUser', [_userEmail, _userPassword])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`callproc`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#callproc) to call stored procedures.

```
cur.callproc('spCreateUser', [_userEmail, _userPassword])
```

Flask-MySQLdb is a wrapper for MySQLdb, so this would work anywhere you were using that driver.  It's not specific to the Flask extension, or even MySQLdb.  Any package that conforms to PEP 249 would support this.